# Transparency is not preserved while creating CGImage

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

While converting byte array data in the format of RGBA, in to CGImage, image is rendered without transparency.

Code snippet:

```
                      int colorArrayLength = 100 * 100 * 4;

                      byte[] colors = new byte[colorArrayLength];

                        for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100; i++)
                        {
                            // Set the Red color
                            colors[4 * i] = 255;

                            // Set the Green color
                            colors[4 * i + 1] =0;

                            // Set the Blue color
                            colors[4 * i + 2] = 0;

                            // Set the Alpha color
                            colors[4 * i + 3] = 125;
                        }

                        var byte1 = colors;
                        var maskdata = NSData.FromArray(byte1);
                        image1 = new CGBitmapContext(maskdata.ToArray(), (int)100, (int)100, 8, (int)(100 * 4), CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast).ToImage();

                        // Get the UIImage
                        streamImage = UIImage.FromImage(image1);
```

Expected Result : UIImage should be with Red color with transparency
Actual Result : UIImage displayed without any transparency

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?.

Comment: What is the swift tag for?  Your question does not appear to have anything to do with Swift.

Answer (score 2):

`CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast` means the image is stored with “pre-multiplied alpha” color channels (which is the normal way to store color channels).

[*Compositing Digital Images*](https://keithp.com/%7Ekeithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf), the seminal paper by Porter and Duff, explains premultiplied alpha in §2, “The Alpha Channel”:

> What is the meaning of the quadruple (r,g,b,a) at a pixel?
> How do we express that a pixel is half covered by a full
> red object? One obvious suggestion is to assign (1,0,0,.5}
> to that pixel: the .5 indicates the coverage and the (1,0,0)
> is the color. There are a few reasons to dismiss this proposal, the most severe being that all compositing operations will involve multiplying the 1 in the red channel by the .5 in the alpha channel to compute the red contribution of this object at this pixel. The desire to avoid this multiplication points up a better solution, storing the *pre-multiplied* value in the color component, so that
> (.5,0,0,.5) will indicate a full red object half covering a
> pixel.

So in a normal image, each of the r, b, and g channels should be no more than the value of the a channel. In your example code, you're using uint8 components instead of float components. You should be storing 125, not 255, in the r channel, because you're storing 125 in the a channel.

You should also explicitly specify the byte order. You're assuming that the r channel is at the lowest address in the pixel and the a channel is at the highest address. You can be sure that's how CoreGraphics interprets the bytes by specifying `CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big`.

Here's a Swift playground showing how the premultiplied alpha works:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics

let gc = CGContext(
    data: nil,
    width: 2, height: 2,
    bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 8,
    space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
    bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
        | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue)!

gc.data!.advanced(by: 0)
    .copyMemory(from: [128, 0, 0, 128] as [UInt8], byteCount: 4)
gc.data!.advanced(by: 4)
    .copyMemory(from: [128, 0, 0, 255] as [UInt8], byteCount: 4)
gc.data!.advanced(by: 8)
    .copyMemory(from: [255, 0, 0, 128] as [UInt8], byteCount: 4)
gc.data!.advanced(by: 12)
    .copyMemory(from: [255, 0, 0, 255] as [UInt8], byteCount: 4)

let image = Image(gc.makeImage()!, scale: 1, orientation: .up, label: Text(""))

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ZStack {
    Color.black
    Circle().fill(Color.blue)
    image.resizable().interpolation(.none).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}.frame(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Here's the live view:

[image: the live view of the playground]

The top left shows r=128 a=128. Since the image in this quadrant is partially transparent, you can see the blue circle blending with the red image to make a purple quarter-circle.

The top right shows r=128 a=255. Since it's fully opaque, you cannot see the blue circle at all, but the redness is only at half of maximum intensity.

The bottom left shows r=255 a=128. Because r > a, the red image is *luminescent* in this quadrant, meaning that it contributes “extra light” here, which is why the quarter circle is more pink than purple—the image is contributing more than a normal share of redness. The Porter-Duff paper discusses luminescence in §4.4.

The bottom right shows r=255 a=255, which is fully opaque and fully red.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coregraphics.cgimagealphainfo?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#remarks)

> Pre-multiplication means that the values for red, green and blue have
> already been multiplied by the alpha value. This helps speed up
> rendering as it avoids three multiplications per pixel at render time.

I take that to mean you should use `Last` instead of `PremultipliedLast`

Comment: Unfortunately, CoreGraphics doesn't actually support `CGImageAlphaInfo.last`. If you pass it to `CGBitmapContextCreate`, it returns nil.